# Looking for Power Transformer for ECC99 OTL Headphone Amp

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, audio, headphones, tube

I'm planning on building an OTL headphone amp using a pair of ecc99 (I got matched pair of soviet 6n6p in my hand). Eliminating output transformer would reduce the complexity of the circuit and the budget also. Cause it is very difficult to find a proper output transformer for headphone. I could only found output trans like 5k:32ohms, 7K:32ohms here in Japan, which might not suitable for my application to drive headphones vary from 250ohms to 600ohms.

And I found a perfect project from here:
[OTL WCF headphone amp build + awesome prototype material](https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/tubes-valves/256334-otl-wcf-headphone-amp-build-awesome-prototype-material.html)
[image]

But it doesn't mention about any of power transformer. I have decided to make vintage style power supply, which has following topology:

Power Transformer AC250V*2 -> Full Wave Rectifier Tube(Maybe use 6x4) -> Choke -> Filter Cap -> Resistor -> Filter Cap

Any suggestion for how much power do I need for power transformer and how many H of choke coil?

Comment: There are free simulators that have tubes/valves in their armoury of components. Try one.

Comment: can you give some example? or how can I roughly estimate the current of each tube so I can choose proper power transformer?

Comment: microcap 12 is free and still available. A lot of folk use LTSpice but I don't know if it has tubes. Microcap certainly does and is my absolute preferred choice over any other.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.